# How can I prevent a Spinner dropdown from closing when a ListView behind it updates?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, spinner

I'm having an issue where I have a Spinner (dropdown) in a tab above a ListView, and when the dropdown menu is open and the ListView behind it (not the one in the dropdown) updates, the dropdown menu closes. Is there any way of getting around this? The ListView can have pretty frequent updates.

My layouts are structured as follows:

- A 2 page view pager with a ListView (Let's call them list1 and list2) in each page
- A Tab Holder (modeled after the SlidingTabLayout android code sample found [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html)) with two tabs

The dropdown is only relevant to the second page/tab. The first tab just has a TextView. The second tab has a TextView, a Button, and a Spinner with 0 height. I have configured the button to call `performClick()` on the spinner, which opens the dropdown menu.

My problem is, if you click the button, the dropdown menu opens, but then if anything updates in list1 or list2, which causes the ListView to refresh, the dropdown menu is dismissed. There is nothing really out of the ordinary in the code (and there's a lot of it for this) so I don't think there's anything worth including but I can share specifics if it would help

Comment: It's difficult to visualize what you're saying.  Please include screenshots and layout code to help us.

Comment: did you got any solution for this ?